# Multiple user collections

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm building a web app that needs two kinds of users.

1. Admins
2. Customers

Now I could put these both into the same `Meteor.users()` collection and add a bool such as `{customer: true}` but I'd like to keep them separate so the customers have their own collection while inheriting methods from the main users collection such as password hashing etc.

Is their a way to 'extend' from the main users collection and create a seperate collection such as 'Customers' while still maintaining all the functionality of the original users collection?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider finding a own way of hashing without trying to extend the core packages. You may find some useful info in this hackpad.
[hackpad link](https://meteor.hackpad.com/SRP-bcrypt-J5mdBojeVfe)